# Reference to the figure on the word

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, labels, links

I would like to put a link to a figure on a specific word. In my case a link on a person's name linking to table figure with his biography. Could you help?

Comment: `\usepackage{hyperref}` in the preamble and `\hyperref[figlabel]{John doe}` in the document body (where John Doe is the text and `figlabel` is the label for the figure).

Comment: Thanks. This is working. I apologise for dumb question since I'm a beginner.